# Dir.bat equivalent that recognises Chinese characters

Tags: list, batch-file, directory, cjk

When I use either my dir.bat file or the below command, it works but if there are Chinese characters, it'll replace them with "?".
cmd  /c  dir  /b  > "%temp%\Dir.txt"  & notepad  "%temp%\Dir.txt"

Is there an equivalent that'll recognise both Chinese and Latin characters?

Many thanks!

Comment: First of all, change the name of your batch file to something which cannot be confused for a well known command. Next, if this is in a batch file, it is already being run by `cmd`, which means you should remove `cmd /c`.  However, as you are wanting to maintain characters in potentially multiple languages, it may be prudent to keep `cmd`, but choose to format its output as unicode. Example: **1.** ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /U /D /C "Dir /B 1>"%Temp%\Dir.txt""```, **2.** ```@Start "" %SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe "%Temp%\Dir.txt"```.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znhqGrF4gVQ

1. In the folder's explorer bar type "cmd" then press enter.
2. Type "dir /b" then press enter.

The result gives you the list of filenames in the folder, which includes Chinese characters.

It doesn't give the full file path however.